# Getting run-time "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" for the Activity Class written/defined in ".aar" file Android Studio

Tags: android, aar

I have created one library project, in that I created one media player. Now my intention is to make this Media Player reusable in any Android App, I mean I'll provide ".aar" file to any android developer then he/she will add it as dependency in there Android project then, by simply calling the MediaPlayerActivity in their code they can use it.

Now, the problem is, if I use this Media Library project as project module (e.g. ***implementation project(":mymediaplayer")***) then everything works fine, but when I creates ".aar" file of that Media Library and tried using it as dependency (e.g. ***implementation(name: 'mymediaplayer', ext: 'aar')***), then I am getting **Run time "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"** for the MediaActivity.class written in the same library which I'm calling from separate Android Project.

Below are the steps how I'm using .aar--

1] I Copied "mymediaplayer.aar" file in to the "libs" folder of my android project.

2] Written below code in to the Project-level build.gradle file

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

3] Below is the dependency in App-level build.gradle file--

```
implementation(name: 'mymediaplayer', ext: 'aar')
```

4] Below is how I am calling MediaActivity.class from my Android project--

```
Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MediaActivity.class); // Getting error on this line 
videoIntent.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", "http://xxxxyyyyzzz.mp4");
                    startActivity(mediaIntent );
```

5] Result:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/my_package/MediaActivity;
```

I hope given information is enough to understand my problem, but still if you guys need more details, please let me know.

I found couple of question asked before on StackOverflow for the same problem but unfortunately none of them I found useful for me and that's why I need suggestion(s) from you experts. Thank you

Comment: Did you try to include just like this `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])` And you may have to add the `group` and `version`

Comment: @Vall0n in this case I am getting "Duplicate Class" error for all the classes written in  my 'mymediaplayer' library.

Comment: did you try to remove `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])` from your library build gradle file. And also `flatDir {dirs 'libs'}` from the `repository` section

Comment: Alternatively you could try to add your dependency like this `implementation(groupValue:mymediaplayer:versionValue)`. In your example you just relay on the name for the dependency resolution

Answer (score 1):

I declared the dependencies with a transitive option, like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation(name: 'mymediaplayer', ext: 'aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
}
```

The error would be gone then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but unfortunately getting the same error.